# Bash script containing sed command throwing error on Cygwin

Tags: xml, windows, bash, sed, cygwin

I have created a simple bash script on windows and tried to execute it on Cygwin.

The command is replacing `<asOf>` tag value from `2013` to `2014` at 17th line in XML file.

```
#!/bin/bash
sed '17 s/<asOf>2013<\/asOf>/<asOf>2014<\/asOf>/' XML_FILE
```

If I execute the `sed` command on cygwin directly, I am able to get the results. But running bash script on cygwin displayed the following error:

> sed: -e expression #1, char 3: extra characters after command

Comment: Make sure the script doesn't contain any Windows carriage returns -  `\r` characters.

Comment: i have considered that part. Changed the EOL conversion from windows to Unix

Comment: open it in vi and with a cat to see if there is no an extra charactere arround your `s/` that a windows editor don't show (but bash well)

Comment: You are probably using some kind of variables in your command. If they happen to contain a slash `/`, you can use another delimiter: `sed '17 s#<asOf>2013</asOf>#<asOf>2014</asOf>#' file`

Comment: @NeronLeVelu: This suggestion is great because Windows editor is sometimes so stupid to spaces at its own free will. Had such issues before

Comment: @S-J Doing sed '17{s/<asOf>2013<\/asOf>/<asOf>2014<\/asOf>/}' XML_FILE will also be a good try.